# How can I combine like x values on a scatter plot in excel?

Tags: excel

So I've got a column of profits for each sale and a column of which province the sale was in. I want to make a scatter plot but group the x values by province instead having 8400 different x values. I have tried for days to get this to work, even grouping the provinces into single bigger cells using VBA didnt work.

Edit:
So for example Ill have

`ontario 12
vermont 3
ontario 6
ohio 8`

and I want it to graph 3 columns, with the ontario column having a point at 12 and 6.

I want it to do that but I have 8400 data points so I cant do it by hand...

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a scatter plot.

Comment: Well, I want the individual points to show up as dots, I just want multiple dots in each column. So like a compressed scatter plot?

Comment: Maybe your question would be easier to answer if we had some idea what your data looks like.

Comment: I've added an example. Ill also attach my data.

Comment: Yes, it will still seperate my <20 provinces into 8400 different x values. Here is the file in question, I'm trying to compare province and profit as individual values(dots not bars) while being able to see which province they are from (not spread out horizontally). http://www.filedropper.com/sample-superstoresalesexcel

Comment: I think you'll need to re-organize your data if you want this type of plot.  https://superuser.com/questions/400158/excel-scatter-chart-with-grouped-text-values-on-the-x-axis

Comment: Thank you Ill give this solution a shot and report back

Comment: Yeahh not exactly a perfect solution on the newest version of excel, he may be onto something with the line graph though. Will investigate.

Comment: Yeah I've got this method to work small scale, but once you reach over 255 data points, when you go to click switch row/column it will not allow you.

Comment: I got it to work by using columns with numbers instead of province names, and a lot of manual labor.